# How to avoid losing items dropped by enemies in the Gutter?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Twice in the first run through the Gutter I've seen the "Pick up item" prompt appear just for a fraction of a second after killing an enemy. It then disappears. There is no glowing mass, and no prompt. Reloading the game doesn't help. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

These "items" are affected by gravity. Basically, if there's a hole in the floor (in the Gutter there are many) then the item will fall through, given a big enough gap. Basically, the only way to grab these items are:

- Be quick. Mash the button if you have to, and *expect* a drop regardless, even if one is not forthcoming.
- Check the lower levels. Some platforms are multi-levelled. It is possible the item may have stopped below.

For the record: reloading the game does not "reset" the location of general item drops. This only happens for special equipment (like NPC drops, for example). If you quit the game with a few of these items around, they will disappear when you re-load the game.

Comment: Unfortunately mashing might not working if you are not standing still, so kill something, get into position as if the item is there, stand still, and then press the button.  Of course you can just let it fall down... it's usually torches and useless broken weapons or life gems.